# Rdlc convert date to alphabet number

Tags: c#, vb.net, reporting, rdlc

can i convert Date `CDate` parameter to alphabetical date

eg: Convert `'08.12.1994'` to `'Eighth December : Nineteen Hundred Ninety-Four'`

Comment: No, i don't think you can do it easily. You'd rather convert it in your code and pass the parameter already converted.

Comment: @Pikoh so, is there any built-in method of c# to convert int to alphabets?

Comment: Nothing built in I know. You may try with [Humanizer](https://github.com/Humanizr/Humanizer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you guarantee the date in DD.MM.YYYY format, this VB code might be something like what you want.

```
Function ConvertDate(ByVal date As String) As String
    Dim textDate As String = ""
    Dim nDay As Integer = CInt(date.Split(".")(0))
    Dim nMonth As Integer = CInt(date.Split(".")(1))
    Dim nYear As Integer = CInt(date.Split(".")(2))
    Dim hundreds As Integer = 0
    Dim notHundreds As Integer = 0

    //Convert day to text.
    Select Case (nDay)
        Case 1
            textDate += "First"
        //Fill in cases 2-30
        Case 31
            textDate += "Thirty-First"
    End Select

    //Add your separator.
    textDate += " "

    //Convert the month to text.   
    Select Case (nMonth)
        Case 1
            textDate += "January"
        //Finn in cases 2-11
        Case 12
            textDate += "December"
    End Select

    //Add your separator.
    textDate += " : "

    //Split the year.
    hundreds = nYear / 100
    notHundreds = nYear - 100 * hundreds

    //Add the hundreds part of the date if there is one.
    If hundreds <> 0 Then
        textDate += NumberUnder100ToText(hundreds)
        textDate += "Hundred "
    End If

    //Add the not hundreds part if there is one.
    If notHundreds <> 0 Then
        textDate += NumberUnder100ToText(notHundreds)
    End If

    //Remove extra trailing space if present.
    textDate = textDate.Trim()

    Return textDate
End Function

Function NumberUnder100ToText(ByVal number As Integer) As String
    Dim text As String = ""

    If number < 20 Then
        //Covers 1 to 19
        Select Case (number)
            Case 0 //Do nothing
                text = ""
            Case 1
                text = "One"
            //Cases 2-18
            Case 19
                text = "Nineteen"
        End Select
    Else
        //Add the 10s place
        Select Case (number / 10)
            Case 2
                text = "Twenty"
            //Cases 3-8
            Case 9
                text = "Ninety"
        End Select

        //Add the 1s place
        If (number Mod 10 <> 0) Then
            text += "-"
            text += NumberUnder100ToText(number Mod 10)
        End If
    End If

    Return text
End Function
```